# Same application code but different web.config and different virtual directory session timeout

Tags: asp.net, timeout, directory, virtual, .net-1.1

I have two asp.net 1.1 applications which have the same code but use different web.config settings. They are mapped to two different virtual directories say vd1 and vd2. The login pages hence become  vd1/login.aspx and vd2/login.aspx

While I am logged into one app, if I log into the other one, I get logged out of the first one and vice-verca. What can be the reason for this kind of a behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I got the fix. It had to do with the cookiename. I had to give a different cookie name to each copy of the application. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the fix. It had to do with the cookiename. I had to give a different cookie name to each copy of the application. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Hey, just wanted to ask you, how do you have two different web.config files, one for each virtual directory. Won't the virtual directories point to the same physical directory, and thus the same web.config file? I am sorry, but I am not getting this.

Answer (score 0):

well i am not sure,but check in your virtual directories web.config file that ,you haven't used 'clear' tag..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. 
I am also facing the same issue. Where do we neet set the cookiename? Greatful if you can provide an example.

**Edit**: 
I found it..

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".CookieName" loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx" />
</authentication>
```